# How to Get Rid of a Single Border Between a Frame and a Frameset?

Tags: html, iframe, frame, frameset, frameset-iframe

I've got a page with a toolbar in the top frame. I want borders between every other frame except between the toolbar and the two frames it borders.

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<frame src="toolbar.html" name="toolbar">
<frameset rows="44%,*">
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="frame1.html" name="frame1">
  <frame src="frame2.html" name="frame2">
</frameset>
<frameset rows="28%,28%" cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="frame3.html" name="frame3">
  <frame src="frame4.html" name="frame4">
  <frame src="frame5.html" name="frame5">
  <frame src="frame6.html" name="frame6">
</frameset></frameset></html>
```

So, how would I remove the boarder between "toolbar" and "frame1"/"frame2" while leaving all the other boarders in place (including the one between frame1 and frame2)? I'm open to using iframes if that would do it, but I would need to see a code example because I have never used them.

Comment: Impossible, because your toolbar frame, not being inside a frameset element but followed by a frameset element is discarded from the DOM in modern browsers.

Comment: can I add a frameset like frameset rows=35,*?

Comment: Also, I could make the toolbar an image file. The toolbar doesn't need to work, this is just an interactive mockup of what will later be all PHP dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can gain sufficient control over the frameborders to do what you want. Best would be to not use framesets at all, but if you really want to, your best hope is to hide all the frameborders and have 1px of dark margin or padding around the edge of the html in each frame to stand in for the frame borders, except in the places where you want the borders not present.